# Is it legally allowed to distribute a .NET framework?

Tags: .net, frameworks, publish, eula

I'm creating an application in the .NET framework(in the language of C# to be precise). I want to publish it to the internet as soon as i finished. My application uses the .NET framework 3.5. So, is it **legally** allowed to distribute an application(in a .zip form) with the .NET framework(inside the zip file) to run the application?(in my case .NET 3.5).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO users can not and should not give _reliable legal_ advices with all their consequences and implications for different countries/jurisdictions and copyright laws.Note that the answers you get here won't help you if you get sued.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xak0tsbd(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Microsoft will pay you for redistributing it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues instead of directly about programming. **[See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)** for details and the **[help]** for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question isn't clear - when you say *"with the .NET framework(inside the zip file)"* I'm assuming you mean the Redistributable Package, rather than the actual zipped-up framework itself.

If so, see [Redistributing the .NET Framework [3.5]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xak0tsbd(v=vs.90).aspx):

> The Microsoft Software License Terms for the .NET Framework give you specific rights to redistribute the .NET Framework. You can manually launch and install the .NET Framework on a computer, install it across a network using an electronic software distribution tool, or launch and install it as part of the setup program for a .NET Framework application.

The rest of the page has more details.